# download videos from youtube

Tags: swift3

please how can i get the link of download videos from youtube in swift language by the api?
or on the another way?
please help

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [YoutubeSourceParserKit](https://github.com/mojilala/YoutubeSourceParserKit).  Follow the example but instead of playing the video save the URL with the method of your choice (it NSURLSession, Alamofire.download or whatever you are using for http).

Comment: thank you my friend but not working have huge problem this is build in the swift 2 i think have you the updated?

Comment: There is no swift 3 branch, but its only one file and 170 lines so its easy enough to just pull the file into your project and have the migrator convert it to swift 3.

Comment: thank you very much my friend

Comment: Does it work for now ?